# Error:Application development based on opencv

Tags: .net, vb.net, opencv, visual-studio-2008

I done my opencv code using windows console application vs2008 than i make that as a dll and used it in windows application vb.net.
while running i got this error.i didn't get where i did mistake.The error is like this

```
unhandled exception has occurred in your application if you click continue the application will close immediately.unable to load aranga.dll.The application failed to start because its side by side configuration incorrect.
```

aranga.dll is my dll having my coding opencv coding part.please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an application that needs to load DLLs, the system first searches the DLL in the application's directory (i.e. the same folder as your .exe), and then if it can't find it continues to search in the directories defined in the `PATH` environment variable, and also `C:\Windows\system32`.

If your DLL is present in any of these locations, the problem might be that your DLL has dependencies that are not being found. I suggest you use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to assist you on this task.